# How to install kivy under ubuntu?

Tags: python, software-installation

Can someone provide me with clear install instructions for kivy?

Their install instruction is not very good. But I have tried, which I've found here:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kivy
```

Put their example inside kivytest.py 
and get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kivytest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ImportError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Comment: Did the install commands work or were there errors?

Comment: Some missing dependencies: "
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 kivy : Hängt ab von: python3-kivy (>= 1.8.1-daily0+201404281119-2007-testing42~ubuntu14.04.1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.

Comment: Ok well that's the problem then. Did you try running `sudo apt-get install python3-kivy`?

Comment: I get something similar then: "Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 python3-kivy : Hängt ab von: python3-pygame ist aber nicht installierbar
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete."

Comment: Do you have python3 installed?

Comment: Yeah, it comes onboard with 14.04.

Comment: OK well I suggest you keep going; your last error was about python3-pygame not being installed - install that, and if that says a dependency is missing, install the missing dependency, and so on.

Comment: I tried http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu but there is an ffmpg not working..

Comment: Can't you install via `apt-get`?

Comment: Is there a apt-get possibility? I now seem to get kivy to run under python2: the error was:
sudo get-apt install python-kivy instead of python3-kivy

Comment: I can't use python3 though. python2 kivytest.py shows following in the terminal:
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/empedokles/.kivy/logs/kivy_14-04-30_1.txt
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.8.1-dev
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 157 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, 
shortened..

Answer (score 4):

In ubuntu [Kivy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/kivy) is built from the packages `python-kivy`, `python-kivy-examples`.

So install following packages.

```
sudo apt-get install python-kivy python-kivy-examples debhelper python python-all-dev cython libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev
```

Comment: how to install it in virtualenv? possibly using pip  install I like to keep everything in virtualenvs, I  hate using apt-get for python packages unless I absolutely have to

Comment: Can you dot hat using `dh-virtualenv`? [See](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=virtualenv&searchon=names)

Answer (score 4):

The [installation page of Kivy](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html) gives a hint:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/pygame  
sudo apt-get update
```

I used Synaptic package manager for this purpose as this way I could see directly whether python3-pygame is available or not, but the terminal command will do the job as well. Everything executed successfully on Ubuntu 14.04.

Let's move on to python3.

Reason: pygames is only shipped in a version for python 2 with Ubuntu at this point in time. There are some pages describing how to create a python3 version yourself (for the German users above: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Pygame), but obviously this is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 2):

You may be using Python3. To install Kivy under Python 2.x and Python 3.x:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy # stable builds repository
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python-kivy python3-kivy python-kivy-examples
```

<sup>**Reference:** [Installation on Linux — Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Kivy - Multimedia / Multitouch framework in Python is in the default repositories in Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04, and 19.10 and later. To install it, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-kivy # for Python 3.x # 16.04, 18.04 + 19.10 and later
```

or

```
sudo apt install python-kivy  # for Python 2.x in 18.04 and earlier
```

python3-kivy has been dropped from the default repositories in Ubuntu 19.04 because of a software bug that also affects python3-kivy in Ubuntu 18.04. There is a workaround for this bug which is described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153116/which-ubuntu-for-kivy-and-python3/1153168#1153168).