# Which Ubuntu for Kivy and Python3

Tags: python3, kivy

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it is a fact of life that it does not support Kivy with Python 3.

(If you want to feel 'enlightened' try reading the following exchange: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/kivy/kivy/5994/491939788)

QUESTION: Is there any Ubuntu version that can do the trick?

Comment: What is the problem? Please update your question with information on what the problem is. Don't expect us to follow and read links to work out your problem or the solution to it.

Comment: 1. yes it does; the ONLY conclusion you can make is that the one in the repo does not work. That does not mean kitty + p3 + 18.04 does not work. "Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 14)"  looks like a bug: the 0 should be at least 11 so best course of action: report it. 2. any version. 3. as noted in the answer: use the official version instead of the one on the repo's.  This one https://launchpad.net/~kivy-team/+archive/ubuntu/kivy already has support for 19.10

Comment: Soren A: sorry for not being clear. My problem is the one listed under "Code and Logs" in the URL I referenced.

Comment: Rinzwind: being inexperienced, which doc do I follow to "use the official version instead of the one on the repo's"? Thks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug, which I confirmed in Ubuntu 18.04, is probably the reason why python3-kivy was dropped from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 19.04. This bug has been fixed and python3-kivy has been restored to the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 19.10 and later.

A later version of Kivy 1.11.1 (instead of 1.9.1) can be installed with `pip3 install kivy` in a [Python virtual environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603935/pyvenv-vs-venv-vs-python-virtualenv-vs-virtualenv-and-python-3/603937#603937) using Python 3 virtual environment creator (*python3-virtualenv*) from the default Ubuntu repositories. Try running `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` before `pip3 install kivy` to upgrade your pip3 to the latest version as I did.

Below are the results of running the Hello World test program from the link in your question with Kivy 1.11.1 in a Python 3 virtual environment. The Python 3 code ran without any errors, detected OpenGL and my NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver, and output this window:

[image]

Comment: Thks, karel. I tried your suggestion this morning, but unfortunately the "pip3 install kivy ran into trouble right at the start; a short snippet of the error messages:

Comment: Try running `pip3 install --upgrade pip` first to upgrade your pip3 to the latest version as I did.

Comment: damn it, installed successfully, and the hello world app ran ok! Can't thank you enough.